# Reverse URL error in form action

Tags: django, django-forms, reverse, django-urls

I have this  bit of HTML with a reverse URL:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action ="{% url 'add_location' %}">{% csrf_token %}
```

I am trying to have it work with this url pattern here:

```
url(r'^location/add$', AddLocation.as_view(), name="add_location"),
```

But I am receiving the following error:

```
Reverse for 'add_location' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I think there is something fundamentally wrong happening here, but I can't seem to figure out what it is. I may not understand reverse urls correctly. I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: Is that urls.py included in project's urls.py?

Comment: Did you rename your project? The `urls.py` that django is using has no patterns at all `0 pattern(s) tried: []`

Comment: Rohan, yes it is.
Burhan Khalid, no I didn't rename my project, but I did just add in the `name="add_location"` part in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured it out, this wasn't extremely obvious.

In whatever `urls.py` file that you are referring to the reverse in, you need to `import reverse`. I thought I could get away with not importing it because I was using it in a template, but nope, you need to import it in that urls.py for those names to work in any templates.